# How do I test an entity with ManyToOne relationship through REST Assured?

Tags: java, jackson, entity, rest-assured, many-to-one

I have an entity that has a many to one relationship. I manually verified this works using postman, but when I try to test this in a unit test the company property is null when it comes through on the api even though it is set in the setup. I have no idea why this is the case

**User class**

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity(name = "User")
@Table(name = "users")
@NamedQueries(
        @NamedQuery(name = CustomNamedQueries.USER_GET_ALL_IN_COMPANY_DEFINITION, query = CustomNamedQueries.USER_GET_ALL_IN_COMPANY_QUERY)
)
public class UserEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JsonBackReference
    @JoinColumn(name = "company_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private CompanyEntity company;
}
```

**Company Class**

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity(name = "Company")
@Table(name = "companies")
public class CompanyEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Email
    @NotEmpty(message = "A company email is required.")
    @Column(name = "company_email")
    private String companyEmail;

    @JsonManagedReference
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "company", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<UserEntity> users;
}
```

**Test Class**

```
@QuarkusTransactionalTest
public class UserControllerIntegrationTest {

    @Inject
    CompanyRepository companyRepo;

    @Inject
    UserRepository userRepo;

    private CompanyEntity company;

    @BeforeEach
    void setup() {
        company = saveCompany();
    }

    @AfterEach
    void cleanup() {
        userRepo.deleteAll();
        companyRepo.deleteAll();
        company = null;
    }

    @Test
    void test_getUsersInCompany() {
        // Given
        UserEntity user1 = saveFromAPI();
        UserEntity user2 = saveFromAPI();

        // When
        List<UserEntity> users = getUsersInACompany();

        // Then
        assertEquals(2, users.size());
        assertThat(users.get(0)).isEqualTo(user1);
        assertThat(users.get(1)).isEqualTo(user2);
    }

    private UserEntity saveFromAPI() {
        UserEntity user = createAdminUser(company);
        return given()
                .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
                .body(user)
                    .post("/api/v1/companies/{companyId}/users", company.getId())
                .then()
                    .statusCode(201)
                    .extract()
                        .as(UserEntity.class);
    }

    public static UserEntity createUser(CompanyEntity company, boolean isAdmin) {
        LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.now();
        UserEntity user = new UserEntity();
        user.setAddress(createAddress());
        user.setCompany(company);
        user.setDateOfBirth(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH).format(localDateTime));
        user.setEmploymentStartDate(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH).format(localDateTime));
        user.setEmail(RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(6) + "@mailer.com");
        user.setTitle(RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(4));
        user.setEmployeeNumber(RandomStringUtils.randomNumeric(5));
        user.setJobTitle(RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(8));
        user.setStatus(RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(7));
        user.setQualification(RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(10));
        user.setMobile(RandomStringUtils.randomNumeric(10));
        user.setFirstName(RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(10));
        user.setLastName(RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(10));
        user.setIsAdmin(isAdmin);
        return user;
    }
}
```

**Postman body json (this works)**

```
{
    "company": {
        "id": 1
    },
    "address": {
        "number": "14",
        "street": "Harcourt Street",
        "city": "Dublin 5",
        "county": "Dublin",
        "country": "Ireland",
        "postcode": "R34 X943"
    },
    "title": "Mr",
    "firstName": "Bilbo",
    "lastName": "Baggins",
    "employeeNumber": "1B345",
    "jobTitle": "Manager",
    "status": "Active",
    "employmentStartDate": "10-04-2000",
    "dateOfBirth": "21-09-1980",
    "qualification": "IT Manager",
    "mobile": "0987654321",
    "email": "bilbo@baggins.com",
    "isAdmin": true
}
```

[image: Debugger before sending in API]
This is a snapshot of the debugger when the user is created and before the api call is made. The Company attribute is set in the User object.

[image: Debugger after sending in API]
This is a snapshot right as the POST endpoint is hit. The company attribute that was set before the call is now null.

Any ideas as to why this is coming through as null?

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is that you use `@JsonBackReference` with the company:

```
@JsonBackReference
private CompanyEntity company;
```

which prevents "deserialization" of the company in the user entity.

If you need the company to be deserialized in the user entity inside your api endpoint, then you can use `@JsonIdentityInfo` instead:

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(
   generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,
   property = "id")
public class UserEntity {
```

and

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(
   generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,
   property = "id")
public class CompanyEntity {
```

If you need more details and find other options, you can refer to: https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-bidirectional-relationships-and-infinite-recursion#managed-back-reference

Answer (score 0):

Join on [@moemen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5231798/moemen) answer i may add that you might want to consider use of DTO objects for serialisation and exposure to endpoints, mapping them to your Entities with mappers (model mapper, mapstruct and others), it is best not to expose Entities to endpoints it is extra work but it is safer to use DTO.

Comment: Is a Dto with nested entities ok, or should it be Dto with nested Dto's?